# Make textview scrollable if two textview overlaps

Tags: android, layout, scroll, textview

Is it possible to make **textview** dynamically **scrollable** when two text view **overlaps** in Android devices with small screen size. I need textview scrollable in my custom list that is being populated from json data.

Comment: Perhaps it might be better to define an individual layout for small screens with less information on it which don't overlap.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion!! but my need is to make uniform layout for all screen size.

Answer (score 1):

You can use DocumentView.DocumentView is actually a subclass of ScrollView.Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

Use each `TextView` inside `ScrollView` and set height of ScrollView

Comment: Thank you Sunil Sahoo. I tried your suggestion but nothing changed. In my case textviews are overlapping horizontally i.e right side of left textview is overlapping with left side of right textview.